# Select from dropdown Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

New to Selenium. I'm trying to get it so that I can enter a name into a search box and then click on the correct name.

I have managed to write some code to go to a website and then enter what I want and press the search button. The problem is that it then shows a list of items so I'd have to click again.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep

index = 'AMZN'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.marketscreener.com')
sleep(6)
text_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#autocomplete')
text_box.send_keys(index)

#select.select_by_index(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='recherche_menu']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/button/img").click()
```

When I enter the name and don't click It presents a dropdown list so I am trying to select the first item from the dropdown as that is usually what I will want.

I attempted this by using the commented out select.select_by_index code line. But it doesn't quite work.

I just tried also using `text_box.send_keys(Keys.DOWN, Keys.RETURN)` to move down into the dropdown field, but this doesn't work and just returns the same as what I currently get from clicking.

To be clear what I mean is that currently the code will return this:
[image: Current return]

But I want it to go straight to the Amazon page so it will return this:
[image: Want to go to this page]

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page use many `JavaScript` to listen the action of the mouse and the key.If you didn't focus on the searchbox,the dropdown will be disappeared.(and you couldn't find it in the source code).

Try to use `ActionChains`,this works fine on my PC:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep

index = 'AMZN'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.marketscreener.com')
action = ActionChains(driver)

sleep(4)
text_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#autocomplete')
action.move_to_element(text_box)
action.click(text_box)
action.send_keys(index)
action.perform()

sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="AC_tRes"]/li[1]').click()
```

---

If the result couldn't show you,maybe you need to increase the time of `sleep()`.

Comment: thanks! Never heard of ActionChains but it is working!